# too many ties in knn? how to solve this problem

Tags: r, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour, train

I use the knn model to train my data and then eliminate accuracy via cross-validation, but when I use the following code, I get the error:

```
Error in knn3Train(train = c(1680, 300, 480, 240, 1020, 360, 240, 360,  : 
    too many ties in knn
```

My code

```
 libray("caret")
 train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)
 SOC=read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
 model <- train(soc~., data=SOC, trControl=train_control, method="knn")
 predictions<-predict(model, SOC[,1:7])
```

How can I fix the problem?